# Match Arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working on a tic tac toe project with a simple 3x3 grid.  I'm pushing the index of each selected box to an array for each player.  In an attempt to check for a winner, I can't seem to get my player arrays to match up with my winner array.  I've tried the indexOf method and the inArray method--but to no avail.

Here's my winner array:

```
const winners = [
    [0,1,2], 
    [3,4,5], 
    [6,7,8], 
    [0,3,6], 
    [1,4,7], 
    [2,5,8],
    [0,4,8], 
    [2,4,6]
];
```

And code which tracks player moves (including the push of selected index value). Note that my console log is showing the correct index values being pushed to the player's array.

```
//Check for player move and change box to active if available
    currentPlayer = 0;
    player1Mouseover()
    $boxes.click(function(){
          if ((currentPlayer == 0) && ($(this).hasClass('box box-filled-1') || $(this).hasClass('box box-filled-2'))){
            alert("Whoa whoa--no no bad selection kiddo. Try again.");
          } else if ((currentPlayer == 0) && ($(this).hasClass('box'))){
            //highlight selected box with a 'O' image 
            $(this).addClass('box-filled-1');
            //increment total player moves
            move ++;
            //push player one's selections to array
            player1Selections.push(($(this).index()));
            //set to player two
            currentPlayer = 1;
            //set conditions for mouseover events
            player2Mouseover();
            //check to see if there is a winner
            checkWinner();
            //add active class to player two's image at top of screen
            $('#player2').addClass('active');
            //hide active class for player one's image at top of screen
            $('#player1').removeClass('active');
          } else if ((currentPlayer == 1) && ($(this).hasClass('box box-filled-1') || $(this).hasClass('box box-filled-2'))) {
            alert("Whoa whoa--no no bad selection kiddo. Try again.");
          } else if ((currentPlayer == 1) && ($(this).hasClass('box'))){
            //highlight selected box with a 'X' image 
            $(this).addClass('box-filled-2');
            //increment total player moves
            move ++;
            //set back to first player
            currentPlayer = 0;
            //set conditions for player one mouseover events
            player1Mouseover();
            //check for a winner
            checkWinner();
            //change classes for player one and two
            $('#player1').addClass('active');
            $('#player2').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

here is my arraysEqual and checkWinner function which I'm only testing on player one for the moment.

```
//Check to see if there is a winner
    function arraysEqual(a, b) {
      if (a === b) return true;
      if (a == null || b == null) return false;
      if (a.length != b.length) return false;

      // If you don't care about the order of the elements inside
      // the array, you should sort both arrays here.

      for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
      }
      return true;
    }



  function checkWinner(){
        isEqual = arraysEqual(winners,player1Selections);
        console.log(player1Selections);
        if (move >= 5){
            if (isEqual){
                finish.style.visibility = "visible";
                board.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                console.log("winner");
            } else {
                console.log("no winner");
            }
        }
```

complete code here if needed [github](https://github.com/pythoncreate/tic-tac-toe/blob/master/js/main.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare arrays in javascript this way.

```
[0,1,2]==[0,1,2] // false
```

So comparing arrays (or one subarray with a different array, but same values) doesn't work. Both arrays are not the same, only the values are the same.

You can define your own function to achieve this:

```
Array.prototype.equals = function(array) {
  if(this.length != array.length) return false;
  for(let i=0;i<this.length;i++)
    if(this[i]!=array[i]) return false;
  return true;
}
```

This will work in your case. It is NOT ment to work with all kinds of arrays. If you need a comparation of multidimentional arrays it won't work and you will need to define a function that's complexity is a little higher.

What you need is to compare all the subarrays of the winners array with one array that could match.

This can be done with using the `Array.prototype.some` function: `winners.some((subArray)=>arrayEquals(subArray, the_other_array))` (this statement is true, if one of the subarrays matches the given other array)

Comment: Downvoting without leaving a comment. That's so... great! Realy -.-

Comment: hey just a note but that is NOT me.  I notice a lot of that on my posts--and not sure why mine is downvoted?

Comment: but PS--thanks for your answer--i didn't realize i couldn't compare multidimensional arrays like that

Comment: @JohnRogerson I didn't thought so :) Someone is downvoting all my posts this night. I don't know why. anyway: I hope it helps. if you have any further questions, please feel free to ask. If you like this answer, please select it as the answer, so everybody can see that this question is answered :)

Comment: okay thanks--i'm still a bit blurry using prototypes but will accept yours as the right answer since you pointed me in the right direction.  i added an arrayEquals function to check if values are equal--but I still for some reason can't get it to match.  if you have a second maybe you can just take another quick look at my code--if not no worries.  thanks!

Comment: @JohnRogerson now you check winners vs one subarray. How can I explain that... you're checking `arrayEquals([[01,2],[3,4,5],...], [0,1,2])` and this cannot be true ;) you can use reduce or `Array.prototype.some` to get what you want

Comment: ah ok i see what you're saying---back to the drawing board :(

Comment: @JohnRogerson updated my answer. But you have a different problem: the player also wins if he has an array that looks like `[0,8,1,2]`. So you cannot compare the arrays directly. It's not as simple as you thought at the moment ;) But you will get it. If you have any problems, leave a comment and I will help you

Comment: Okay thanks @JoshuaK appreciate the advice.  I'm going to dig in and try to figure this one out.  Thanks again.